# Specifying the identity variance-covariance matrix for nlme::lme in R?

Tags: r, matrix, structure, covariance, nlme

I am assembling an **R** code file that exhibits various common variance-covariance (VCV) structures for use in `nlme::lme`. I currently have what I believe to be correct code examples for scaled identity, diagonal, compound symmetry, heterogeneous compound symmetry, autoregressive, heterogeneous autoregressive, Toeplitz, and unstructured VCV matrices. For completeness, I am eager to include a simple **identity VCV matrix**, meaning 1's on the diagonal and 0's elsewhere. (I realize such a VCV matrix is not particularly useful in practice, but it is often included as a baseline and for illustration.) However, I have thus far been unable to figure out how to specify the identity VCV matrix and have it fixed such that *after model fitting*, the identity matrix is still in tact.

To make this question clearer, allow me to describe my working example. I have a (meaningless) long-format data table with one subjects identifier column (**S**)={1...20}, one repeated factor (**X**) with three categorical levels {a,b,c}, and one numeric response variable (**Y**). There are 20 subjects, each with one response **Y** for each of the three levels of **X**, resulting in 60 rows in my table. (That is, each subject is measured three times on X={a,b,c}, resulting in 3 measures per 20 subjects = 60 rows.) As I said above, this data itself is meaningless, so any such table is sufficient for addressing my question here.

I know that in `nlme::lme`, the `correlation` parameter sets the off-diagonal covariances, and the `weights` parameter sets the on-diagonal variances. Since repeated factor **X** in this example has 3 levels, the VCV matrix would be a 3 x 3 matrix. My goal is to specify the **identity VCV structure** as having three 1's down the diagonal (the variances) and the rest 0's (the covariances) in this 3 x 3 matrix, and for `nlme::lme` to use this as the VCV matrix during optimization. The fitted matrix can be checked, it seems, with:

```
getVarCov(model, type="conditional")
```

For example, if I specify a *scaled identity* VCV structure (all variances equal, all covariances zero), I can do so like this and get the following output:

```
model = lme(Y ~ X, random=~1|S, data=df, weights=varIdent(form=~X))
getVarCov(model, type="conditional")

Conditional variance covariance matrix
       1      2      3
1 5.9455 0.0000 0.0000
2 0.0000 5.9455 0.0000
3 0.0000 0.0000 5.9455
```

Above, we can see the diagonal has been fit as 5.9455 for all variances (on-diagonal), and all covariances (off-diagonal) are zero.

As one more example, a *heterogeneous autoregressive* structure can be fit like this:

```
model = lme(Y ~ X, random=~1|S, data=df, correlation=corAR1(form=~1|S), weights=varIdent(form=~1|X))
getVarCov(model, type="conditional")

Conditional variance covariance matrix
         1       2        3
1  6.26980 -1.2738  0.75894
2 -1.27380  2.2890 -1.36380
3  0.75894 -1.3638  7.18670
```

Now, what I can't figure out is how to specify and have result a matrix like this?

```
[1  0  0]
[0  1  0]
[0  0  1]
```

The best guess I've come up with, but which does not work, is the following, where the diagonal (`weights`) are set to the identity matrix correctly (I think). But `fixed` seems to have no effect (I'm sure I'm using it wrong) and the resulting VCV matrix does not retain the identity structure after fittitng:

```
model = lme(Y ~ X, random=~1|S, data=df, weights=varIdent(pdIdent(diag(nlevels(df$X))), fixed=TRUE)) # does not work!
getVarCov(model, type="conditional")

Conditional variance covariance matrix
       1      2      3
1 5.9455 0.0000 0.0000
2 0.0000 5.9455 0.0000
3 0.0000 0.0000 5.9455
```

The resulting VCV matrix is indeed *an* identity matrix, but scaled up to, in this example, having 5.9455 on its diagonal, not 1.0000. (It is the same result as the scaled identity example up above.) **How can we force it so the resulting VCV matrix looks like this?**

```
Conditional variance covariance matrix
       1      2      3
1 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
2 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
3 0.0000 0.0000 1.0000
```

I have read the help docs (`?nlme::corClasses`, `?nlme::varClasses`) and see that a `corStruct` object might be useful for creating a custom VCV matrix, but I can't figure out how to do that, and am not sure it is the right approach. I have also played with both `varIdent` (as above) and `varFixed`, to no avail, when setting the `weights` parameter. Any help and sample code anyone can give in this case would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!